# Limit the number of returned integers using PATINDEX

Tags: sql, sql-server, compiler-errors, type-conversion, substring

I have a script that extracts a minimum of five consecutive integers into a `temp` table. How do I limit it so that it returns a minimum of five consecutive integers but a maximum number of 7 consecutive integers?

```
SELECT nv.AdditionalInformation, 
       nv.Id,
       CASE
           WHEN M.FirstMatch > 0
           THEN SUBSTRING(AdditionalInformation, M.FirstMatch-1, N.SecondMatch-1)
           ELSE NULL
       END AS ExtractedTP
INTO #tempExtractedTPNumber
FROM
(
    SELECT ':'+nv.AdditionalInformation+':' AdditionalInformation, 
           nv.Id
    FROM dbo.Reports nv WITH(NOLOCK)
) nv
CROSS APPLY(VALUES(PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', ':'+nv.AdditionalInformation+':'))) M(FirstMatch)
CROSS APPLY(VALUES(PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', SUBSTRING(AdditionalInformation, M.FirstMatch-1, LEN(AdditionalInformation))))) N(SecondMatch);
```

The issue is I have a list of numbers that are returned and majority are five or six digits but there is a record that is returned that has twelve consecutive digits which causes an issue later down the line and I get this error:

> The conversion of the varchar value 'xxxxxxxxxxxx' overflowed an int column

Comment: In the second `apply`, change the `LEN(AdditionalInformation)` to 8?

Comment: @GSerg Thanks for your reply! I get the error `invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.`

Comment: That is because now the second `cross apply` returns 0 when there is no non-digit to be found within the 8 characters, so you have to account for that in the outer `then substring()`.

Comment: Try a CTE where you restrict the data processed to WHERE Len( AdditionalInformation ) <= 8. In essence exclude any data your algorithm can not handle. Or put this condition into your subquery.
Trying to make your algorithm (Substring) handle exceptions for incorrect data selection is futile.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.